# Missing semicolon error for functions returning iterator

Tags: c++, c++11, tree

I am trying to make a rough abstract implementation of an Interval Tree, but I am getting a strange error. All of my functions that return a `std::map<ui16, Node>::iterator` are giving me the error:

> error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'FOO'

Where `FOO` is the name of the function.

`ui16` is simply a `typedef unsigned short`.

Any ideas?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <map>

//Very rough implementation of a specialized interval tree
//TODO: Replace std::map with a custom red-black tree implementation or something similar

template <typename T>
class IntervalTree {
public:

    struct Node {
        Node(T Data, ui16 Length) : data(Data), length(Length) {}
        T data;
        ui16 length;
    };

    inline void clear() {
        std::map<ui16, Node>().swap(_tree);
    }

    inline std::map<ui16, Node>::iterator getInterval(ui16 index) const {
        auto it = _tree.lower_bound(index);
        if (it->first != index) {
            return it--;
        }
        return it;
    }

    inline std::map<ui16, Node>::iterator insert(std::pair<ui16, Node> pair) {
        return _tree.insert(pair);
    }

    std::map<ui16, Node>::iterator insert(ui16 index, T data) {
        //Find containing interval
        auto it = _tree.lower_bound(index);
        if (it->first != index) {
            it--;
        }
        //Its already in the tree
        if (it->second.data == data) {
            return it;
        }

        //If the interval is only 1, just change its value
        if (it->second.length == 1) {
            it->second.data = data;
            return it;
        }

        //Check if its at the right edge of the interval
        if (index == it->first + it->second.length - 1) {

            auto next = it + 1;
            //if it should add to the next interval
            if (data == next->second.data) {
                it->second.length--;
                it = _tree.insert(make_pair(index, Node(data, next->second.length + 1)));
                _tree.erase(next);
                return it;
            } else { //else we should add an interval and modify left interval
                //Modify left interval
                it->second.length--;
                //Insert new interval
                return _tree.insert(make_pair(index, Node(data, 1)));
            }
        } else if (index == it->first) { //if its at the beginning of the interval
            //Insert right interval
            _tree.insert(make_pair(index + 1, Node(it->second.data, it->second.length - 1)));
            _tree.erase(it);
            _tree.insert(make_pair(index, Node(data, 1)));
        } else { //else its in the middle of the interval
            //Insert right interval
            _tree.insert(make_pair(index + 1, Node(it->second.data, it->second.length - (index - it->first) - 1)));
            //Modify left interval
            it->second.length = index - it->first;
            //Insert new middle interval
            return _tree.insert(make_pair(index, Node(data, 1)));
        }
        return _tree.end();
    }

    inline std::map<ui16, Node>::iterator begin() const { return _tree.begin(); }
    inline std::map<ui16, Node>::iterator end() const { return _tree.end(); }

private:
    std::map <ui16, Node> _tree;
};
```

Comment: [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Comment: if you want ui16 to be an unsigned 16 bit integer, define it as `uint16_t` instead of `unsigned short`. This will make your code more portable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[C2146](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xbcaa9t.aspx) gives a rather unhelpful error message but ultimately the problem is you're missing the `typename` keyword where there are dependent scopes. `iterator` depends on the instantiation of `std::map<ui16, Node>` and requires the `typename` keyword to disambiguate your usage. For more information, please consult [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords). For a more helpful error message, see the following example from gcc:

```
main.cpp:83:12: error: need ‘typename’ before 
‘std::map<short unsigned int, IntervalTree<T>::Node>::iterator’ 
because ‘std::map<short unsigned int, IntervalTree<T>::Node>’ is a dependent scope

     inline std::map<ui16, Node>::iterator begin() const { return _tree.begin(); }
```

Just replace `std::map<ui16, Node>::iterator` with `typename std::map<ui16, Node>::iterator` and you're good to go.

Comment: More specifically, `IntervalTree<T>::Node` is a dependent name because some specialisations of `IntervalTree` may not have it, or may have it as something other than a nested type. Consequently, any type consisting of `IntervalTree<T>::Node` (such as your map type) as also dependent names.

Comment: Thank you! Now I am getting a conversion error with the iterator in getInterval() but all the other errors are gone.

Comment: @user3346893 That's because `getInterval` is const. So `_tree` returns a const iterator.